# Excel VBA Userform

Tags: excel, userform

I have created a Userform with multiple worksheets with different months. I can only get the form to work properly for "Sheet7(July)". How do I make the form work on all sheets in the work book? Below is my code for the form. Thank you

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Range("A").Value = tbdaterec
'Range("B").Value = tbdateres
'Range("C").Value = cmblist.Value
'Range("D").Value = tbstudent
'Range("E").Value = tbdatesch
'Range("F").Value = tbrequest
'Range("G").Value = cmbsitelist.Value

erow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


Cells(erow, 1).Value = tbdaterec.Text
Cells(erow, 2).Value = tbdateres.Text
Cells(erow, 3).Value = cmblist.Value
Cells(erow, 4).Value = tbstudent.Text
Cells(erow, 5).Value = tbdatesch.Text
Cells(erow, 6).Value = tbrequest.Text
Cells(erow, 7).Value = cmbsitelist.Value
```

Comment: When you say work for each sheet what do you mean *exactly*? Place the same information from the userform into each sheet in your workbook?

Comment: When I switch to another sheet and try to use the form on that sheet it does not work properly, for example if i select "August" its will not work properly like it did for "Sheet7" . So I am wondering how to incorporate the form to work for all sheets.@ Alex P

Answer (score 0):

In your code do this:

```
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

That will get `erow` depending on which sheet you are on.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes it did ! Thank you sir !@Alex P